# Ergative with Because

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Are these punctuated correctly and is the parenthetical reasoning for each valid and sound?

1. *She's not running for class president**,** because she is scared.* 
   (= comma before "because" means she *is not* running for class president. Period.)
2. *She's not running for class president because she is scared.* 
   (= no comma before "because" means she *is* in fact running for class president but for a reason other than she is scared.)

Comment: Sounded correct to me, but I miss the but in the second line

Comment: What do you think your title means?

Comment: That's a good question.

Comment: What on earth does this question have to do with ergativity?

Answer (score 4):

> She's not running for class president because she is scared

Punctuation alone will not make your second sentence (quoted above) clear and unambiguous. If you want to say that she's running, but not because she's scared (implying another reason), better to relocate *not*

**She's running for class president, but not because she's scared.**